# Send empty POST field in Angular form

Tags: angularjs

I know angular do not send empty fields in form POST but i want exactly opposite of that. If a field is exist in form html then that field must be posted doesn't matter if its blank or have some data so that I can get that field in my function .

```
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.field_name]" ng-trim="false"/>
```

Comment: Why not check if the field exists in your function?

Comment: @detheridge02 I want this empty field in my function , I don't want to check wether its empty or not . I want to check wether it exists in POST or not and fields are dynamic so I don't know the number of fields . So If a certain field just present in POST then I can populate it with custom data (default value) but for that empty fields must get POSTed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialized your field with the empty data.

```
 One <input name="one" ng-init="value = ''" ng-model="value"  /><br /> 
 Two <input name="one" ng-init="value2 = ''" ng-model="value2" /><br />
```

OR :Create a directive

```
myApp.directive('initializeProperty', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.val('');
      }
  };
});


 One <input name="one" ng-model="value" initialize-property ng-trim="false"  /><br /> 
 Two <input name="one" ng-model="value2" initialize-property ng-trim="false" /><br />
```